# Where to store the configuration data for the entire web app in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm current writing a personal time management system, and it turns out that I need to store the configuration data such as the time of availability for other people to sign up for the web app. However, since this system is dedicated for one person's schedule, I do not think I need to use sql database as it will wind up with only one entry. So where can I store this configuration? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing, put it in config/environment.rb

```
AppName::Application.configure do
  config.key = value
  config.key2 = value2
end
```

And in your controller, you can access this by

```
AppName::Application.config.key
```